# Delete databases folder internal storage

Tags: android, file, delete-file

I'm trying to create a reset app functionality for my application and I'm trying to delete all files from internal storage including `files folder`, `databases folder`and `shared preferences`. The problem is that not everytime when I try to delete these folder they are deleted. Sometimes the function which I use to delete the files returns false. In that case my application cannot work properly. Here is what I'm using :

```
 @SuppressWarnings("static-access")
public void deleteAllData(){

    String cache = this.getCacheDir().toString();
    Log.e("","dbPath : "+cache);
    File ChFolder = new File(cache);
    boolean cachee = deleteDirectory(ChFolder);
    Log.e("","Database Folder Delete Success : "+cachee);

    String server = rpc.getCurrentServerName(this);
    int userId = rpc.getUserId(this);

    String userDbPath = "/data/data/"+this.getPackageName()+"/databases/"+Integer.toString(userId)+"_"+server;
    File userDbFile = new File(userDbPath);
    boolean userDbFileTF = userDbFile.delete();
    Log.e("","user Database Folder : "+userDbFileTF);

    String sysDbPath = "/data/data/"+this.getPackageName()+"/databases/stampii_sys_tpl.sqlite";
    File sysDbFile = new File(sysDbPath);
    boolean sysDbFileTF = sysDbFile.delete();
    Log.e("","user Database Folder : "+sysDbFileTF);

    // Delete Databases Folder :
    String dbPath = "/data/data/"+this.getPackageName()+"/databases/";
    Log.e("","dbPath : "+dbPath);
    File dbFolder = new File(dbPath);
    boolean dbFold = deleteDirectory(dbFolder);
    Log.e("","Database Folder Delete Success : "+dbFold);


    // Delete Files Folder :
    String name = this.getFilesDir().toString()+"/users/";
    Log.e("","path : "+name);
    File files = new File(name);
    boolean filesFol = deleteDirectory(files);
    Log.e("","filesFol : "+filesFol);

}

static public boolean deleteDirectory(File path) {
    if( path.exists() ) {
      File[] files = path.listFiles();
      if (files == null) {
          return true;
      }
      for(int i=0; i<files.length; i++) {
         if(files[i].isDirectory()) {
           deleteDirectory(files[i]);
         }
         else {
           files[i].delete();
         }
      }
    }
    return( path.delete() );
}
```

Is there something I'm missing and how can I implement function like `Clear Data`  in Android Settings which will delete the databases too.

Answer (score 2):

Use the following code. It should delete all the data automatically. Make sure no database/file or any cache resource is in-use before proceeding with this:

```
/**
 * Call this method to delete any cache created by app
 * @param context context for your application
 */
public static void clearApplicationData(Context context) {
    Log.i("delete", "Clearing app cache");

    File cache = context.getCacheDir();
    File appDir = new File(cache.getParent());
    if (appDir.exists()) {
        String[] children = appDir.list();
        for (String s : children) {
            File f = new File(appDir, s);
            if(deleteDir(f))
                Log.i("delete", String.format("*** DELETED -> (%s) ***",
                    f.getAbsolutePath()));
        }
    }
}

private static boolean deleteDir(File dir) {
    if (dir != null && dir.isDirectory()) {
        String[] children = dir.list();
        for (int i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
            boolean success = deleteDir(new File(dir, children[i]));
            if (!success) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return dir.delete();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A directory must be empty to be deleted. Here is an example of how to delete files from a directory and then delete the directory itself.

http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0483.html

Comment: If you take a look at my `deleteDirectory()` function I'm using the same method.

Comment: So you are... why don't you log the directory you are trying to delete, and it's contents. Then log the files as you delete them to make sure the method is working and figure out if the directory is actually empty when you attempt to delete it.

Comment: Actually I'm doing this and it returns false when I'm trying to delete them,not always but sometimes.And I can't figure it out why it's not working,because I'm not doing anything special.

Comment: Then post the output of the order it tries to delete files and where it fails