# Delete folder from internal storage in android?

Tags: android, android-storage

How to delete folder(contain some folder and file) from internal storage? Folder have some below tree.

```
folder
|_________  C2 (folder)
             |________1 (folder)
                      |________1.gif
                      |________2.gif
                      |________3.gif
                      |________4.gif
             |________2 (folder)
                      |________1.gif
                      |________2.gif
                      |________3.gif
                      |________4.gif
             |________3 (folder)
                      |________1.gif
                      |________2.gif
                      |________3.gif
                      |________4.gif
             |________4 (folder)
                      |________1.gif
                      |________2.gif
                      |________3.gif
                      |________4.gif
             |________5 (folder)
                      |________1.gif
                      |________2.gif
                      |________3.gif
                      |________4.gif

|_________  C2.xml (file)
```

I want to delete folder and containing all files

```
fil.delete();

System.out.println("boolean =>" + fil.delete());
```

but above code shows false. Please help.

Comment: Check This > http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8311751/delete-databases-folder-internal-storage

Comment: see this link...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10361145/how-to-delete-all-the-files-from-sd-card-in-android

Comment: i have already read the above link but they shows how to delete files not folder

Comment: Follow teedyay's answer in this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4943629/android-how-to-delete-a-whole-folder-and-content

Comment: thanks to every one now my problem will solve but thanks for guiding me Nirav , Mehul , Kalai.

Answer (score 89, accepted):

Check this out.

```
public void deleteRecursive(File fileOrDirectory) {

   if (fileOrDirectory.isDirectory()) {
       for (File child : fileOrDirectory.listFiles()) {
          deleteRecursive(child);
       }
   }

   fileOrDirectory.delete();
 }
```

for explaination [How to delete a whole folder and content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4943629/android-how-to-delete-a-whole-folder-and-content)

Answer (score 8):

You can't delete root folder if sub folder contains any files. So for that you have to first delete each of sub files and then you will able to remove the folder.

Your code is valid, I just update like:

```
 boolean deleted = mypath.delete();
```

ie. `mypath` is your File Directory.

Answer (score 4):

Let me tell you first thing you cannot delete the Rootfolder because it is a system folder. As you delete it manually on phone it will delete the contents of that folder, but not the Root folder. You can delete its contents by using the method below:

```
private void DeleteRecursive(File fileOrDirectory) {
    if (fileOrDirectory.isDirectory())
        for (File child : fileOrDirectory.listFiles())
        {
            child.delete();
            DeleteRecursive(child);
        }

    fileOrDirectory.delete();
}
```

Comment: this code is working if i have one file in my folder but my folder contain folder( this folder contain another folder and last folder have some files ) and file.

Answer (score 1):

Using Apache commons-io, which is just one line of code.

```
FileUtils.deleteDirectory(getAlbumStorageDir(directoryName));
```

Answer (score 0):

For Kotlin, use [Kotlin's standard extension](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io/java.io.-file/delete-recursively.html):

```
File.deleteRecursively()
```