# How to delete all files and folders in one folder on Android

Tags: java, android, file-io

I use this code to delete all files:

```
File root = new File("root path");
File[] Files = root.listFiles();
if(Files != null) {
    int j;
    for(j = 0; j < Files.length; j++) {
        System.out.println(Files[j].getAbsolutePath());
        System.out.println(Files[j].delete());
    }
}
```

It will delete false where `Files[j]` is a folder.

I want to delete folder and all its sub files.
How can I modify this?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3775694/deleting-folder-from-java

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Simplest way would be to use [FileUtils.deleteDirectory](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-1.4/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#deleteDirectory(java.io.File)) from the Apache Commons IO library.

```
File dir = new File("root path");
FileUtils.deleteDirectory(dir);
```

Bear in mind this will also delete the containing directory.

Add this line in gradle file to have Apache

```
compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-io:1.3.2'
```

Comment: compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-io:1.3.2' //for gradle import

Answer (score 74):

Check this link also [Delete folder from internal storage in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13410949/how-to-delete-folder-from-internal-storage-in-android).

```
void deleteRecursive(File fileOrDirectory) {

    if (fileOrDirectory.isDirectory())
        for (File child : fileOrDirectory.listFiles())
            deleteRecursive(child);

    fileOrDirectory.delete();

}
```

Comment: straight forward

Comment: `fileOrDirectory.listFiles()` may return null if there is I/O error when reading the files. This is stated in the documentation : developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#listFiles()

Answer (score 18):

```
File file = new File("C:\\A\\B");        
    String[] myFiles;      

     myFiles = file.list();  
     for (int i=0; i<myFiles.length; i++) {  
         File myFile = new File(file, myFiles[i]);   
         myFile.delete();  
     }  
B.delete();// deleting directory.
```

You can write method like this way :Deletes all files and subdirectories under dir.Returns true if all deletions were successful.If a deletion fails, the method stops attempting to delete and returns false.

```
public static boolean deleteDir(File dir) {
    if (dir.isDirectory()) {
        String[] children = dir.list();
        for (int i=0; i<children.length; i++) {
            boolean success = deleteDir(new File(dir, children[i]));
            if (!success) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    // The directory is now empty so delete it
    return dir.delete();
}
```

Answer (score 8):

if **storageDir** is a directory

```
for(File tempFile : storageDir.listFiles()) {
    tempFile.delete();
}
```

Comment: This wouldn't work if there are any non-empty directories in the directory to delete.

Answer (score 5):

For your case, this works perfectly
http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#cleanDirectory(java.io.File)

```
File dir = new File("dir_path");
if(dir.exists() && dir.isDirectory()) {
    FileUtils.cleanDirectory(dir);
}
```

If you wanna delete the folder itself. (It does not have to be empty). Can be used for files too.

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#forceDelete(java.io.File)

```
File dir = new File("dir_path");
if(dir.exists()) {
    FileUtils.forceDelete(dir);
}
```

Comment: It would be nice for you to format a code snippet within your answer, rather than simply linking a link. Also, try and explain exactly what you providing as an answer.

Comment: Don't forget to add the commons io jar to your project. [apache commons jar link is here ] (http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/download_io.cgi)

Answer (score 4):

You can check like this:

```
for(j = 0; j < Files.length; j++) {

    if(file.isDirectory()){
        for(File f : file.listFiles()){
        System.out.println(Files[j].getAbsolutePath());
        System.out.println(Files[j].delete());
    }
    else {
        System.out.println(Files[j].getAbsolutePath());
        System.out.println(Files[j].delete());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

you can try this code to delete files and subfiles

```
public void deleteFile(File f){
String[] flist=f.list();
for(int i=0;i<flist.length;i++){
    System.out.println(" "+f.getAbsolutePath());
    File temp=new File(f.getAbsolutePath()+"/"+flist[i]);
    if(temp.isDirectory()){
       deleteFile(temp) ;
       temp.delete();
    }else{
    temp.delete();
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Beginning with Kotlin 1.5.31 there is a Kotlin extension method that works as follows:

```
val resultsOfDeleteOperation = File("<Full path to folder>").deleteRecursively()
```

Per documentation:

> Delete this file with all its children. Note that if this operation fails then partial deletion may have taken place.
> Returns:
> true if the file or directory is successfully deleted, false otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

// Delete folder and its contents

```
public static void DeleteFolder(File folder)
{
    try
    {
        FileUtils.deleteDirectory(folder);
    } catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log.e(" Failed delete folder: ", ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

// Delete folder contents only

```
public static void DeleteFolderContents(File folder)
{
    try
    {
        FileUtils.cleanDirectory(folder);
    } catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log.e(" Failed delete folder contents: ", ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Docs: [org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.cleanDirectory](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#cleanDirectory(java.io.File))

Answer (score 1):

#### `rm -rf` was *much* more performant than `FileUtils.deleteDirectory` or recursively deleting the directory yourself.

After extensive benchmarking, we found that using `rm -rf` was multiple times faster than using `FileUtils.deleteDirectory`.

Of course, if you have a small or simple directory, it won't matter but in our case we had multiple gigabytes and deeply nested sub directories where it would take over 10 minutes with `FileUtils.deleteDirectory` and only 1 minute with `rm -rf`.

Here's our rough Java implementation to do that:

```
// Delete directory given and all subdirectories and files (i.e. recursively).
//
static public boolean deleteDirectory( File file ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

    if ( file.exists() ) {

        String deleteCommand = "rm -rf " + file.getAbsolutePath();
        Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();

        Process process = runtime.exec( deleteCommand );
        process.waitFor();

        return true;
    }

    return false;

}
```

Worth trying if you're dealing with large or complex directories.

Answer (score 1):

As a kotlin extension function you can do this

```
fun File.deleteDirectoryFiles(){
    this.listFiles().forEach {
        if(it.isDirectory){
            it.deleteDirectoryFiles()
        }else{
            it.delete()
        }
    }

    this.delete()
}
```

Then you can just do

```
file.deleteDirectoryFiles()
```

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me. "imagesFolder" has some files and folders which in turn has files.

```
  if (imagesFolder.isDirectory())
  {
       String[] children = imagesFolder.list(); //Children=files+folders
       for (int i = 0; i < children.length; i++)
       {
         File file=new File(imagesFolder, children[i]);
         if(file.isDirectory())
         {
          String[] grandChildren = file.list(); //grandChildren=files in a folder
          for (int j = 0; j < grandChildren.length; j++)
          new File(file, grandChildren[j]).delete();
          file.delete();                        //Delete the folder as well
         }
         else
         file.delete();
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

## #1

```
File mFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/folder");
try {
    deleteFolder(mFile);
} catch (IOException e) {
    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Unable to delete folder", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

public void deleteFolder(File folder) throws IOException {
    if (folder.isDirectory()) {
       for (File ct : folder.listFiles()){
            deleteFolder(ct);
       }
    }
    if (!folder.delete()) {
       throw new FileNotFoundException("Unable to delete: " + folder);
    }
}
```

#### #2 (Root)

```
try {
    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
    DataOutputStream outputStream = new DataOutputStream(p.getOutputStream());
    outputStream.writeBytes("rm -Rf /system/file.txt\n");
    outputStream.flush();
    p.waitFor();
    } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
       Toast.makeText(getContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**This Method Will Delete All Items inside folder:**

```
String directoryPath = context.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS) + File.separator  + context.getString(R.string.pdf_folder) + "/";

File file = new File("your dir");   //directoryPath       
String[] files;      
files = file.list();  
for (int i=0; i<files.length; i++) {  
    File myFile = new File(file, files[i]);   
    myFile.delete();  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this methods to delete folder and its sub-folders with files
this is working fine.

```
public static void deleteFolders(File folder){
    File[] subfiles;
    if(folder.isFile()){folder.delete();}
    else
    if(folder.isDirectory()){
        if(folder.listFiles().length>=1){
            try{
                subfiles=folder.listFiles();
                for(int f = 0;f<subfiles.length;f++){
                    if(subfiles[f].isFile()){
                        deleteFolders(subfiles[f]);
                    }
                    if(subfiles[f].isDirectory()){
                        if(subfiles[f].listFiles().length>=1){
                            deleteFolders(subfiles[f]);
                        }else
                        deletes(subfiles[f]);
                    }
                }
            }
            finally {
                folder.delete();
                deleteFolders(folder);
            }
        }
    }
}
public static void deletes(File file)
{
    if (file.exists())
    {
        if (file.isDirectory() &&
            file.listFiles().length == 0)
        {
            file.delete();
        }else
        if (file.isFile())
        {
            file.delete();
        }
        else
        { 
        if(file.isDirectory()&&file.listFiles().length>=1){
            File[] files = file.listFiles();
            if (files.length >= 1)
            {
                int i;
                for (i = 0;i < files.length;i++)
                {
                    files[i].delete();
                }
                file.delete();
            }
          } 
        }
    }
```

hope this will help.

Comment: Note that code-only answers are discouraged. I suggest you add explanation, especially regarding the recursive calls to method `deleteFolders` since new programmers often have difficulty understanding how recursion works.